# Optimal positioning of tokens on a unit disk

Tags: geometry, reference-request, optimization

Suppose we have $N$ tokens, labeled $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots,x_N$. Our goal is to place these tokens optimally (defined below) on a unit disk. Formally (and please let us know if our notation is incorrect), let the choice set be denoted by:
$$
X = \{(a,b):a^2+b^2\leq1 \}^N
$$
Then a particular $x \in X$ can be denoted by $x=((x_{1,1},x_{1,2}),(x_{2,1},x_{2,2}),\ldots,(x_{N,1},x_{N,2}))$ in which, for $n=1,\ldots,N, x_{n,1}+x_{n,2}\leq1$. We want a solution for two notions of optimality:

1. Uniform optimality: We want to solve
   $$
   \min_{x \in X} \hspace{0.5cm} \underset{(a,b):a^2+b^2\leq 1}{\int \int} \hspace{0.3cm} \left(\min_{n \leq N} \sqrt{(x_{n,1}-a)^2+(x_{n,2}-b)^2} \right) \hspace{0.2cm} db \hspace{0.2cm} da
   $$
2. Minmax optimality: We want to solve
   $$
   \min_{x \in X} \hspace{0.5cm} \max_{\{(a,b):a^2+b^2\leq 1\}} \hspace{0.5cm} \min_{n \leq N} \sqrt{(x_{n,1}-a)^2+(x_{n,2}-b)^2} 
   $$

While it looks a bit technical when you write it down, it feels like a pretty simple question and one that must have been studied previously. If anybody can suggest a solution and/or point us to a reference, we would very much appreciate it.

Comment: To clarify: you're talking about the unit disk (including its interior), as opposed to the unit circle (just the circumference), right?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes -- that's correct. Thanks for noting that. I'll edit accordingly.